# how to extract data from pcap file

Tags: networking, memcached, wireshark, tshark

I have a few pcap files, I can see the memcache protocol in wireshark and its corresponding data, but when I use tshark to batch export data, it only shows one character(0x0b), why?

the command I use: tshark -Y "memcache contains set" -r input.pcap -T fields -e memcache.value 
Thank you! 
BTW, memcache key works fine. And I can't share the files here as they are confidential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$tshark -r 3006-example.cap -Y "memcache.command==set" -T fields -e memcache.value
hello, world!
noreplyset
```

Test file: that attached to [Wireshark bug 3467](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3467)

I do note that 0x0b is  not a printable ascii character. The memcache dissector assumes that the 'value' is an ascii string.

If you look at the 'value' field in the appropriate packet in your capture file, is it an ascii string ?

edit: looking at the [memcache protocol spec](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt), it appears that the 'value' field should be treated as "unstructured data" and *not* as an ascii string. Please feel free to file a bug report at [bugs.wireshark.org](http://bugs.wireshark.org)

Comment: Thank you, you are right! The value is binary data, do you have any suggestion that I can extract this payload? @willyo

Comment: Nothing comes to mind ....  (short of getting the bug fixed, either by fixing it yourself or by filing a bug report:).     :)